# Почему не отправляется сообщение zeroMQ

Tags: python, сокет, tcp, zeromq

Создаю сервер zeroMQ

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send(b"World")
```

На другом компьютере клиент стучится по адресу 213.158.1.6:5555 (фиксированный адрес сервера)

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to hello world server…")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://213.158.1.6:5555")
    print("Sending request %s …" % request)
    socket.send(b"Hello")
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message))
```

**Почему сообщения не доходят? Компьютеры в одной wifi сети**

Comment: А порт у вас открыт на сервере, чтобы снаружи можно было к нему подключаться?

Comment: @Avernial, порт 5555 открыт в винде. запускаю сервер, но netstat показывает, что такой порт не слушается, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было в винде открыть порт в настройках системы.